Has Logback's JMX configuration feature gone for good?
We used to be able to change our logback configuration at runtime via a JMX MBean. This used to be enabled by adding <jmxConfigurator/> to the config file.
This doesn't work any more and on startup logback reports
Ignoring unknown property [jmxConfigurator] in [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]

I can see that the related classes were deleted in a commit related to LOGBACK-1655

https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/fa3de69304

I can also see that the documentation refers to this as a "Legacy" feature

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html
https://logback.qos.ch/news.html#1.3.0

What I can't work out is if this functionality was removed without replacement? Is there some other library we need to pull in to get JMX functionality back?

Please [edit] to avoid the impression (or the misunderstanding) that you are asking for recommendations of libs or tools, because that makes your question off-topic and at risk of being close-voted, closed and deleted.

The question is very clear, specific and has also been answered. I'm not sure why you are putting effort into trying to invalidate it or further comments.

I kind of agree with your question being clear. But you got an answer which just names a lib/tool/extension. This I take that your question, while clear to me and you, is still offering loopholes for those who either intentionally try to misunderstand (in order to have an excuse for advertising something) or really do not get it and hot-shoot an answer in their desperateness to answer something. Those answers cannot be flagged as "Not An Answer", if there is any chance of misunderstanding. That is why.

based on info:
https://logback.qos.ch/news.html
2022-08-28 Release of logback versions 1.3.0 and 1.4.0
Here is a list of changes with respect to the previous version.
• The ch.qos.logback.classic.jmx package was removed for security reasons and for lack of use.

Haven't tried it but https://github.com/Cosium/jmx-configurator-for-logback looks like it restores it.

Interesting @MJB. I haven't seen that. We ended up using the spring boot logging actuator to change log levels in production
